# Angular 2 upload parse CSV

Tags: javascript, angular, api, typescript, opencsv

I'm a beginner in Angular and I'm trying to create a feature of uploading and registering content with CSV files.

It is as follows:

parts.component.html

```
<div class="well">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="file" name="file" (change)="readCsvData($event)" type="file" accept="text/plain">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Enviar arquivo</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

parts.component.ts

```
readCsvData(){
  let csvUrl = event.target;
  this.partService.upload(csvUrl)
}
```

part.service.ts

```
public upload(input: any){
    let url = this.partsUrl;
    let body = this.extractData(input);
    console.log(body);
    // return this.http.post()
  }
public extractData(data: any) {
    const file = data.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      const content = reader.result;
      var lines = content.split("\n");
      var result = [];
      var headers = lines[0].split(",");
      for(var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++){
        var obj = {};
        var currentline = lines[i].split(",");
        for(var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++){
          obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
        }
        result.push(obj);
      }
      JSON.stringify(result);
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
 }
```

But my Upload function only returns Undefined in the varable body, when in fact it should return the array of objects from the extractData function.

Thanks any help!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Rob's answer, but don't use third party packages for simple string operations:

```
<input type="file" accept=".csv" (change)="processFile($event)">

processCsv(content){
    content.split('\n');
    // other sorts of magic
}

convertFile(event: any) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  readFileContent(file).then(content => {
    console.log('This is your file as string: ', content);
    // Operate your string as required in a separate function
    this.processCsv(content)    
  }).catch(error => console.log(error))
}

readFileContent(file) {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.onload = event => resolve(event.target.result)
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error)
    reader.readAsText(file)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try looking into this npm package
csvtojson

also if you are using angular you should be using const and let, try not to use var.

this is how I used it

```
<input type="file" accept=".csv" (change)="convertFile($event)">

convertFile(event: any) {
  this.file = event.target.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(this.file);
  reader.onload = () => {
    this.textToCsv(reader.result);
  };
}
```

https://github.com/Robbie106gti/nc-catalog/blob/master/src/sop/components/csvtojson/csvtojson.component.ts